# Button color does not change when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new for learning vue.Now I have some problems.My code listed below is using for change the button color when you click on it.But now it can not work.Please give me some advice.Thank you very much!

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isActive: [true, false, false, false],
    movies: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(index) {
      this.isActive[index] = !this.isActive[index];
    }
  },
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in movies">
      <button :class="{active: isActive[index]}" @click="onClick(index)">{{ item }}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it is an array, use Vue.set or this.$set ;)

Comment: You are directly changing the array index value, which does not trigger [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) and rerender of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with array in Vue 2 the best way to updating array indices by $set method.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isActive: [true, false, false, false],
    movies: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(index) {
      this.$set(this.isActive,index,!this.isActive[index])
    }
  },
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in movies">
      <button :class="{active: isActive[index]}" @click="onClick(index)">{{ item }}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```